# Some numpy functions accept passing 'None' to arguments whose default value is None, others don't. Why is that?

Tags: python, numpy

See for example this code:

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import date

x = np.array([1, 2, 3], dtype=None)
y = np.is_busday(date(2023, 1, 1), busdaycal=None)
```

The definition of x works fine, while the one for y yields the error

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
is_busday() argument 4 must be numpy.busdaycalendar, not None
```

Is this desired behavior? If yes, how does this make sense? It seems inconsistent to me.

Comment: This just looks like bad documentation of the function signature. But in any case, you will inconsistencies like this in numpy, unfortunately, especially in the more aracane parts of the API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `is_busday` is compiled code, so it's hard to look at its details.  Also it is subject to some `numpy` coding quirks, especially if it isn't widely used.  The docs says it was added version 1.7.0, quite some time ago.

The full error message:

```
In [56]: np.is_busday(['2011-07-01', '2011-07-02', '2011-07-18'],busdaycal=None)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[56], line 1
----> 1 np.is_busday(['2011-07-01', '2011-07-02', '2011-07-18'],busdaycal=None)

File <__array_function__ internals>:200, in is_busday(*args, **kwargs)

TypeError: is_busday() argument 4 must be numpy.busdaycalendar, not None
```

`is_busday(*args, **kwargs)` is a very general signature.  So my guess is that the TypeError is raised by code somewhat deep in the function code, and not subject to conventional signature handling.

So despite the documentation it isn't checking for a defaukt valu, but whether that keyword is used at all.  If used it checks if the value ok.

numpy/core/src/multiarray/datetime_busday.c

is the file that implements this function

```
if (!PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, kwds,
                                    "OO|O&O&O&O!O:busday_offset", kwlist,
                                    &dates_in,
                                    &offsets_in,
                                    &PyArray_BusDayRollConverter, &roll,
                                    &PyArray_WeekMaskConverter, &weekmask[0],
                                    &PyArray_HolidaysConverter, &holidays,
                                    &NpyBusDayCalendar_Type, &busdaycal,
                                    &out_in)) {
        goto fail;
    }
```